# Could not click on the button (selector) which appears after hovering on another element with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am using this code, I want to click the button "Add item" which appears after hovering on another button (element) "Add item or folder"

```
//helpers.js

module.exports = {
    click: async function(page, selector) {
        try {
            await page.waitForSelector(selector)
            await page.click(selector)
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Could not click on selector: ${selector}`)
        }
    },

//Test.js

const click = require('../lib/helpers').click
describe('Click Add item or Folder', () => {
        it('Click item', async () => {
            await click(page, '#add-item')
        })
```

```
<div id="add-button" class="sc-imDdex jzqRTr" style="display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
<div class="sc-fguZLD kbXAta">Add Item or Folder</div>
<span class="isvg loaded sc-jFpLkX kxsRNE"><svgxmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="14" height="14" viewBox="0 0 14 14"><path fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M14.999,7.99938887 C14.999,8.6099105 14.5043608,9.10454969 13.8938392,9.10454969 L9.10377196,9.10454969 L9.10377196,13.8938392 C9.10377196,14.5042026 8.6089746,14.999 7.99861113,14.999 C7.38824766,14.999 6.89345031,14.5042026 6.89345031,13.8938392 L6.89345031,9.10377196 L2.10416082,9.10377196 C1.49379735,9.10377196 0.999,8.6089746 0.999,7.99861113 C0.999,7.38824766 1.49379735,6.89345031 2.10416082,6.89345031 L6.89345031,6.89345031 L6.89345031,2.10416082 C6.89345031,1.49379735 7.38824766,0.999 7.99861113,0.999 C8.6089746,0.999 9.10377196,1.49379735 9.10377196,2.10416082 L9.10377196,6.89345031 L13.8930614,6.89345031 C14.5035831,6.89345031 14.9982223,7.3880895 14.9982223,7.99861113 L14.999,7.99938887 Z" transform="translate(-1 -1)"></path></svg></span>
<div class="sc-lffWgi eyEQQM">
<div style="padding: 8px 0px; display: block;"><a href="/add-item" id="add-item">
<div class="sc-fGSyRc kxLJRt"><i class="sc-dCVVYJ htCwhs" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/icons/new-item.svg&quot;);"></i>
<span class="sc-huKLiJ eXtCps">Add Item</span></div></a><a href="/add-folder" id="add-folder">
<div class="sc-fGSyRc kxLJRt"><i class="sc-dCVVYJ htCwhs" style="background-image: url(&quot;/images/icons/new-folder.svg&quot;);"></i><span class="sc-huKLiJ eXtCps">Add Folder</span></div></a></div></div></div>
```

Please help me, how I can click on selectors "add item" or "add folder"? Maybe I need to use evaluate but I don't get it how to use it.

[image]

Comment: Describe in more detail what happens, is there an exception being thrown, and if so, on which line? There are many reasons why `click()` can fail. The element could have 0 width or height, it could be covered by another element, or maybe it cannot be scrolled to. Where does `page` come from? Are you sure the page is loaded by the time the test starts running?

Comment: What I can suggest is to create a toy project with Puppeteer and a single static HTML page. Shouldn't take more that 10 minutes. And get the test working there first.

Comment: Works for me. I made this 1-file project if anyone wants to play: https://pastebin.com/UxekVEfS

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Thank you for the reply. I need to hover on another element before I can observe this button. Page fully loaded, this code works fine on this page for other buttons, but not for this particular one.

Comment: @blex Thank you, I will check.